Transaction block inclusion question
I am trying to buy a token right when it becomes available on pump.fun. Now the problem I am having is that my transactions take too long to be included in a block. https://solscan.io/tx/3f9KVeimU1fLrpyrwioBMfYhm6GMKcVMn1Ey2SEyDJ6Ji7DjsbfG5D25FhF3wr9EgYJfcfxDDR51HXQ2UeP3rJ2Y this is one of my transactions that landed. It did so, 34 seconds after the coin was created and around 33 seconds after I have submitted it with numerous RPCs. How come that https://solscan.io/tx/PKzrRE6U6nqymV127LLLQRdibS81C5fZ8TGe3hHh3HVLN4RxmJBZJUfhS47uw42g5YtsGrChk3NaBJJ7bBvmB8R this transaction was included in 3 seconds? It doesn't use jito and my transactions have both larger ComputeUnitPrices, and lower ComputeUnitLimits and yet they take orders of magnitude longer to be included. I've already tried raising the ComputeUnitPrices to 10 times of what can be seen in my previous example, but that didn't help much.


Please paste information as text rather than screenshots.

I have links in my text to the transactios.

I edited my question since the hyperlinks couldn't be seen well. Now there are the raw links.

I mean the main.py output. Posting info - including logs - as text ensures that other people with the same log output can find your post. It also allows people helping you to highlight and copy the text.

I mean it's my code, so I doubt anyone on the internet is going to have the same output.

Good point. In this case, using actual text (like others do) allows people to read your code's output without having to read a screenshot that's formatted for someone else's screen.

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?

No, not really, but I appreciate you at least trying to answer my question, unlike the other guy.
